# How to delete child records instead of setting foreign key to null

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, cascade

I have a User and a set of Authorities in a one-to-many relationship:

User.hbm.xml:

```
<set name="authorities" table="authorities" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key column="user_id" />
    <one-to-many class="com.ebisent.domain.Authority" />
</set>
```

When I delete a user, I want to delete the authorities as well, but what is happening is that the child table's foreign key (authorities.user_id) is set to null instead. Then I get the following error and the User delete is rolled back:

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

The authorities.user_id update to null is not rolled back, however.

How can I delete Authorities when I delete the parent User?

EDIT:
I got this working by explicitly deleting the authorities, calling `refresh()` on the user, then deleting the user, but I would like to know the "right" way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird, a cascade `all-delete-orphan` should cascade the `delete` operation from the parent to the children. So the following should suffice to get the children deleted:

```
Parent p = (Parent) session.load(Parent.class, pid);
session.delete(p);
session.flush();
```

Do you get a different result when using `all,delete-orphan` or even more simply `delete` (you shouldn't). Is the assocation bidirectional? If yes, could you show the other side and the corresponding mapping?

> The association is only from parent to child, and I get the same results with all, delete-orphan, and delete, BUT...I didn't have session.flush(), and that appears to solve the problem.

The explicit flush might help. But it shouldn't be necessary. I *think* that defining the foreign key as non nullable would help to get the correct behavior:

```
<set name="authorities" table="authorities" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key column="user_id" not-null="true"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.ebisent.domain.Authority" />
</set>
```

Not tested though.

Comment: Wouldn't you need an inverse="true" on the relation to have the child records actually deleted ?

Comment: Hi, Pascal, nos. The association is only from parent to child, and I get the same results with all, delete-orphan, and delete, BUT...I didn't have session.flush(), and that appears to solve the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: @nos IMO, `inverse=true` shouldn't be necessary with a uni-directional association.